# How to refer to variables inside the html template?

Tags: html, django, forms

I have a beginners question. 
I followed a very quick tutorial on how to enter a data from a frame into database (http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-insert-data-into-a-database-from-an-HTML-form-in-Django.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Create a Post </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Create a Post </h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
Title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br/>
Content: <br/>
<textarea cols="35" rows="8" name="content">
</textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

In the HTML above - I used name="title" and name="content" inside the views.py

```
def createpost(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.POST.get('title') and request.POST.get('content'):
                post=Post()
                post.title= request.POST.get('title')
                post.content= request.POST.get('content')
                post.save()

                return render(request, 'posts/create.html')  

        else:
                return render(request,'posts/create.html')
```

and that works perfectly, the data is entered into the database.

Now I want to work with a free template I found on the internet. I have already edited the other parts of the HTML file, the remaining part is to 
work with the contact-form here below. The difference is they are using 'this.value' to pass the content of a field. Before I could distinguish between title and content, but now it's just one variable. How can I refer to that variable in my views.py ?
The copy of the code of my interest is below.

```
<div class="services_dark sj" id="signup">
       <div class="container">
            <h3 class="m_3"><center>Interested to join us?</center></h3>
            <div class="contact-form">
               <form method="post" action="contact-post.html">
                 <input type="text" class="textbox" value="First Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}">
                 <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Last Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last Name';}">
                 <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Email address" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email address';}">
                 <input type="submit" value="Join">
               </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But the `this.content` is just some JavaScript to edit the placeholder (although it is probably better to use `placeholder="First Name"` instead).

Comment: You need to give those input elements `name` attributes, just like you did in the original template.

Answer (score 0):

The `this.value = '';` does *not* refer to the values in a view. It is used to remove the placeholder from the `<input>` field (and put it back, given the input field loses focus and the user did not enter any content). It is thus some JavaScript to "animate" the webpage.

That being said, it is more declarative to use the [**`placeholder="..."`** field [html.com]](https://html.com/attributes/input-placeholder/) here, like:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Last Name">
<input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Email address">
```

There are however some drawbacks. For example most translation software will *not* translate the placeholders in order to not break certain JavaScript functions.

Comment: thanks, and how do I access value in "First Name" variable from a function inside views.py, so the input lands in the database table ?

Comment: You should give the `<input>`s a `name="..."`, and then [handle the POST request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/).